# Email verification using pattern

Tags: reactjs, email, email-validation

I have used a the pattern

```
  inputProps={{
                pattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
              }}
```

but its throwing a console warning
Pattern attribute value [a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/v: Invalid character in character class

Any potential fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the inputProps the error was gone when given directly on the textfield like this  :-

```
  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
```

Instead of

```
inputProps={{pattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
              }}
```